# ProgressBar Indeterminate AutoReverse code sample

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

Does anyone have a good example of an IsIndeterminate = True progress bar with the following behavior. We want the bar to be of some specific length say maybe 300 pixels. Then within the bar we want a smaller bar about 30 pixels wide that slides back and forth. The bar should move from the left to the right, "bounce" off the right end and then right to left, repeat. I assume that we need to set RepeatBehavior to Forever and AutoReverse to True but am unsure on how to style this widget.

Comment: A progress bar is to convey the status of a a task.   I think you are looking for StoryBoard.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.aspx

Comment: Yes. This exactly what I need. Thanks for the input. That gave me the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A progress bar is to convey the status of a a task.

I think you are looking for StoryBoard.

[Storyboard Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.aspx)